# Fastest way to find first match index of lots of strings in large text

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, text, find

I have implemented a quick find algorithm in python 2.7.13. It does what I want but I have small performance issues. These are my algorithms specificities :

- I have a text that is an HTML article, it is generally between 5 000 to 50 000 characters but it can be as big as 300 000 characters.
- I have a list of "words" that can contain special characters (é,à,ø,/...) and spaces, generally hundreds to a few thousands words. Words are 2 to 256 characters long.
- I need to ignore found items contained in HTML tags
- I need indexes in text of matches
- I only need the first match for each words

What I have is this implementation :

```
def find_indexes(text, words):
    words_indexes = []
    found_words = []
    authorized_characters = [u' ', u'.', u':', u';', u'?', u'!', u'¿', u'¡', u'…', u'(', u')']

    text_length = len(text)

    for j, word in enumerate(words):
        i = 0 

        # This loop serves to go to the next word find if the first one isn't valid (contained in another word or in HTML tag)
        while i != -1: 
            i = text.find(word, i + 1)

            if i + 1 + len(word) < text_length:

                # We check the before and after character of the word because some words can be contained in others
                # Like "vision" is in "revision". As well as being contained in HTML tags
                before = text[i - 1]
                after = text[i + len(word)]
                if (before in authorized_characters and
                    after in authorized_characters and not
                    (before == u'.' and after == u'.')):
                    words_indexes.append(i)
                    found_words.append(word)

                    i = -1

    return words_indexes, found_words
```

And with big words list and big text it starts to take quite some time (not humanly big but it is not the only treatment I make since it's a part of a Django view, so improving time is always good.

With [theses 1282 words](https://pastebin.com/5ZDn0Uvn) and [this 231884 characters long text](https://pastebin.com/QwXZpmUp) (taken and treated from a [Waitbutwhy article](https://waitbutwhy.com/2015/06/how-tesla-will-change-your-life.html)), I manage to reach around a ~0.3s execution on my computer.

But I feel like there is a better way since the `find()` method is taking most of the calculation time as you can see with this [line_profiler](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler)

```
Total time: 0.28045 s
Function: find_indexes at line 332

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
   332                                           @line_profiler
   333                                           def find_indexes(text, words):
   334         1            4      4.0      0.0      words_indexes = []
   335         1            2      2.0      0.0      found_words = []
   336         1            2      2.0      0.0      authorized_characters = [u' ', u'.', u':', u';', u'?', u'!', u'¿', u'¡', u'…', u'(', u')']
   337                                           
   338         1            2      2.0      0.0      text_length = len(text)
   339                                           
   340      1283         4362      3.4      0.7      for j, word in enumerate(words):
   341      1282         1646      1.3      0.3          i = 0
   342                                           
   343      3436        11402      3.3      1.8          while i != -1:
   344      2154       543861    252.5     86.2              i = text.find(word, i + 1)
   345                                           
   346      2154        22153     10.3      3.5              if i + 1 + len(word) < text_length:
   347                                           
   348                                                           # We check the before and after character of the word because some words can be contained in others
   349                                                           # Like "vision" is in "revision". As well as being contained in HTML tags
   350      2154        16388      7.6      2.6                  before = text[i - 1]
   351      2154        19939      9.3      3.2                  after = text[i + len(word)]
   352      2154         7720      3.6      1.2                  if (before in authorized_characters and
   353       531         1468      2.8      0.2                      after in authorized_characters and not
   354       135          278      2.1      0.0                      (before == u'.' and after == u'.')):
   355       135          783      5.8      0.1                      words_indexes.append(i)
   356       135          428      3.2      0.1                      found_words.append(word)
   357                                           
   358       135          573      4.2      0.1                      i = -1
   359                                           
   360         1            2      2.0      0.0      return words_indexes, found_words
```

Comment: What purpose is "index" being put to use here - it doesn't make a large amount of sense in an HTML document... As using a proper HTML parser and looking at the actual text content would make more sense, but it'd be quite awkward to get back the physical position it occurred in the source after parsing it.

Comment: Well actually we highlight specific words in text and we add HTML tags to do so, we need the indexes to know where to put the tags.

Comment: I've had a go at what I think is a fairly neat solution to your problem... it generates an html document from your example text file with the found words highlighted in yellow.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of using an HTML parser (so it filters out the text elements from the document to avoid finding text within attributes/tags), a compiled regular expression (it can scan for all words at once rather than looping N many times (your main bottle neck)):

```
import ast
# regex (not the builtin one) and bs4 need to be pip installed 
import regex
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Parse the document so we don't have to worry about HTML stuff
# and can find actual text content more easily
with open('text_to_find_the_words.txt') as fin:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fin, 'html.parser')

# Get the words to look at and compile a regex to find them
# Might already be a list in memory instead of a file.
with open('list_of_words.txt') as fin:
    words = ast.literal_eval(fin.read())
    matching_words = regex.compile(r'\b(\L<words>)\b', words=words)

# For each matching text elements, do the highlighting
for match in soup.find_all(text=matching_words):
    subbed = matching_words.sub(r'<span style="background: yellow;">\1</span>', match))
    match.replace_with(BeautifulSoup(subbed, 'html.parser'))

# Write the results somewhere (probably to a HttpResponse object in your case)
with open('results.html', 'w') as fout:
    fout.write(str(soup))
```

You'll need to adjust this to highlight a word only once if needs be.

Comment: This is interesting, I will take a look